# How I can write this lambda expression without a return statement?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

The following method implements a `BiFunction` that takes a `Map<String,String>` and a value to search. It searches for an `Entry` in the `Map` that contains the given value and returns the corresponding key.

This implementation works, but I'd like to write the lambda expression without a return statement, in order to make the code more elegant.

```
private BiFunction<Map<String, String>, String, String> findName = (m, s) -> {
    Map.Entry<String, String> e = 
        m.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null && !entry.getValue().isEmpty() && entry.getValue().equals(s))
         .findFirst()
         .orElse(null);
    return e != null ? e.getKey() : null;
};
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get rid of the `return` statement, as well as the curly braces, the body of the lambda expression has to be a single expression whose type is the return type of the lambda expression - `String` in your case.

Your `findFirst()` returns an `Optional<Map.Entry<String,String>>`. You want to map that to an `Optional<String>` (where the `String` is the key of the entry) and return `null` if it's empty.

You can achieve that using `Optional`'s `map` method :

```
private BiFunction<Map<String, String>, String, String> findName = (m, s) -> 
    m.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null && !entry.getValue().isEmpty() && entry.getValue().equals(s))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElse(null);
```

Comment: Found a compilation error and fixed it. didn't try to run it though.